# Problema com vírgula cmd

Tags: windows, batch, cmd, wmi

```
C:\Windows\system32>wmic /node:"BR1102013" /user:"vedadmin" /password:"i@M}r43/3g%s,L;" product get name
```

, - Alias não encontrado.

Alguém pode me dizer o porque não consigo usar a vírgula e como resolver isso?

Comment: mudar a senha ?

Answer (score 5):

**TL;DR**

Coloque antes de `,` o `^`:

```
/password:"i@M}r43/3g%s^,L;"
                       ↑
```

**Explicação:**

Todas as versões do DOS interpretam certos caracteres antes de executar um comando. Alguns exemplos bem conhecidos são o sinal de porcentagem `%` e os símbolos de redirecionamento `<` `|` `>`. Também permitem o uso de *carets* `^` para escapar de caracteres especiais.

**Escape Caracteres** (traduzido via google)

```
Caráter a ser escapado  | Sequência de fuga  | Observação
%   %%  Não é sempre necessário em cordas duplas, apenas tente
^   ^^  Não pode sempre ser exigido em cordas duplas, mas não vai doer
&   ^&
<   ^<
>   ^>
|   ^|
'   ^'  Requerido apenas no "assunto" FOR / F (ou seja, entre os parênteses), a menos que backq seja usado
`   ^`  Requerido apenas no "assunto" FOR / F (ou seja, entre os parênteses), se backq for usado
,   ^,  Requerido apenas no "assunto" FOR / F (ou seja, entre os parênteses), mesmo em cordas duplas
;   ^;
=   ^=
(   ^(
)   ^)
!   ^^! Requerido apenas quando a expansão da variável atrasada está ativa
"   ""  Requerido apenas dentro do padrão de pesquisa de ENCONTRAR
\   \\  Requerido apenas dentro do padrão regex da FINDSTR
[   \[
]   \]
"   \"
.   \.
*   \*
?   \?
```

<sup>Fonte: http://www.robvanderwoude.com/escapechars.php</sup>

Comment: muito bom, acredito que possa ser também pelo %, cheguei a procurar mas não encontrei. +1

Comment: Já tentei colocar o ^ mas o resultado foi o mesmo, se alguém tiver alguma outra ideia.

Comment: @ThayllonBarbosa, execute esse comando antes do seu: `setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion`

Comment: Tentei e o resultado foi o mesmo.